# Tex command for changing the heading of references

Tags: bibliographies

I want to submit just the abstract of some paper of mine. There I have mentioned just one reference so I need to give the heading reference and not references. Can somebody please tell how to change it? I am using the following command for reference:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{plain}

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: to be certain, it's necessary to know the document class you're using.  for both `article` and `amsart` you can say `\renewcommand{\refname}{Reference}`.